# LWUIT "Textfield" theming overriden when writing in Blackberry J2ME

Tags: blackberry, java-me, lwuit

For some reason the theming of the Textfield is drawn over (overriden) by a white box that covers it entirely whenever the user begins writing inside the field. The theming returns to normal once the user scrolls away from the Textfield.

Is there any way I can disable this and/or what is causing this?

Edit:

This is the BB before I start writing http://imageshack.us/a/img411/5681/24102012023.jpg

[image]

This is the text field changing when I start writing http://imageshack.us/a/img717/5973/24102012024.jpg

[image]

Comment: can you show the code you use to create the text field?

Comment: Unfortunately it would involve pasting a good chunk of code from the framework :(
But currently I started testing on a standalone app and it's doing the same thing. Just a regular TextField text = new TextField(); gives the same result. On Nokia the field remains the same, but on BB it changes into what I described.

Comment: Ok I added an image. This is also the N8 working normally even when I'm writing http://imageshack.us/a/img821/3301/24102012020.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Blackberry uses native editing since there are too many complexities with accepting any other type of input. Since the RIM API is so limited its really difficult to customize the look of the editing mode there to match the style of LWUIT/[Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/).